# Readable counter time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My script is working well, but the only problem i have.

i want to show the counter in human readable style, becouse now its showing in milliseconds

i want like time left is 1:02 Minutes

so i want to display time left in readable style in browser not milliseconds

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  
  <p>Time left: <span id="timr"></span></p>
  <p id="hpd">Welcome here john</p>
  <p id="shp" style="display:none">Your time is up</p>
<input type="button" value="Hi john" id="btn">
<script>
var SessionTime=100000;
var tickDuration=1000;
var myInterval=setInterval(function(){
    SessionTime=SessionTime-tickDuration
$("#timr").text(SessionTime);
},1000);
var myTimeOut=setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);
$("input").click(function(){
clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
    SessionTime=100000;
 myTimeOut=setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);
});

function SessionExpireEvent()
{ clearInterval(myInterval);
    
    $("#btn").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#hpd").hide();
    $("#shp").show();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace

```
$("#timr").text(SessionTime);
```

with

```
$("#timr").text(`${Math.floor(SessionTime/60000)}:${SessionTime/1000%60}`);
```

---

**However**, your code can be simpler if you don't need to know how much time is left to milliseconds precision.

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) are the only functions in your code that need their arguments in milliseconds.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>Time left: <span id="timr"></span></p>
  <p id="hpd">Welcome here john</p>
  <p id="shp" style="display:none">Your time is up</p>
  <input type="button" value="Hi john" id="btn">
  <script>
    var SessionTimeInSec = 40;
    
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      SessionTimeInSec--;
      $("#timr").text(`${Math.floor(SessionTimeInSec/60)}:${SessionTimeInSec%60}`);
    }, 1000);
    
    
    var myTimeOut = setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent, SessionTimeInSec*1000);
    
    $("input").click(function() {
      clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
      SessionTimeInSec = 40;
      myTimeOut = setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent, SessionTimeInSec*1000);
    });

    function SessionExpireEvent() {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
      $("#btn").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#hpd").hide();
      $("#shp").show();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I did the following changes:

- Change `SessionTime` to `SessionTimeInSec` and divide numbers by 1000.
- Multiple `SessionTimeInSec` by 1000 for the arguments passed to both funtions `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.
- Get rid of `tickDuration` since it will equal to one. Consonantly, change `SessionTime = SessionTime - tickDuration` to `SessionTimeInSec--`.
- Change `$(#timr)` text to `0:0` in `SessionExpireEvent()`

Comment: thanks, this was so good and simple, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I understand that this for learning purposes; however, in this use case the logic could have been written differently to be more intuitive. I will add it to my answer in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this:

```
var mins = Math.floor(SessionTime / 1000 / 60);
SessionTime %= 60000;
var secs = SessionTime / 1000;

$("#timr").text(mins + ":" + secs);
```

Comment: this is not working, because the ouput is Time left: 1.6666666666666667:100

Comment: it shows Time left: 1:100 now, but not counting, it would be good and provide the full working code, coz my coding maybe different from urs